# Storing Double in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of type Integer, is it possible to store a value in it (eg: 1.25) without having to cast it to int therefore losing the bit after the decimal?

Comment: Multiply all your values in your `ArrayList` by 100. And divide them when you extract them

Comment: Not without causing heap corruption. Why wouldn't you just use a `List<Double>`?

Comment: can't you use ArrayList<Double> ?

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot store doubles in `ArrayList<Integer>` without loss of precision. You can, however, store them in `ArrayList<Double>`.

Comment: @DarioPanada, if that solved your problem you should accept NPE's solution as correct (click the check mark)

Answer (score 4):

Use `ArrayList<Number>` instead. In this way, you will be able to store both `Double` and `Integer` instances since both classes derive from `Number` class.